# Error when deleting NSManagedObject

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have three controllers, one to display all data, second the view deleted item and third to edit. All works fine besides from deleting the `NSManagedObject`, currently the app crashes with an error of;

> unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f945b56a680 2015-08-17
>   18:35:08.835 AppTest[8008:435289] *** Terminating app due to uncaught
>   exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[NSManagedObjectContext delete:]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance ... terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
>   (lldb)

Why is this error occurring and how can I delete a `NSManagedObject` within the `UINavigationController` and the popToRootController to segue back to the `collection view` ?

Heres what I have been trying to do in `editViewController`;

```
let context = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext

@IBAction func remove(sender: AnyObject) {

    context?.delete(self.selectedObject)

    var error: NSError?
    context?.save(&error)

    self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)

}
```

**Update**: I was not having a problem using the `popToRootViewController`method but using the delete method which should have been `deleteObject()`. Now i know the problem I see there are many questions on it.

Comment: I wonder that this compiles at all. NSManagedObjectContext does not have a `delete()` method, only `deleteObject()`.

Comment: Actually the `delete` method is part of the [UIResponderStandardEditActions](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponderStandardEditActions_Protocol/index.html) protocol, which is defined as a category on `NSObject` (an "informal protocol"). This explains why the code compiles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `deleteObject()`, not `delete()`, since `delete` is an unimplemented extension on NSObject.

Your code should be:

`context?.deleteObject(self.selectedObject as NSManagedObject)`

Comment: "...delete is a base level function on NSObject." Um, no. And of course, if that had been true, the unrecognized selector exception wouldn't have been thrown in the first place.

Comment: I changed it to "unimplemented extension." In the future, please suggest edits if you find language not to your liking - you have more than enough reputation to improve the language of a post.